# Why is this java code unable to save image in mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have passed BufferedImage as argument from jsp to java with following code:

```
 <%BufferedImage citizen = ImageIO.read(new File(add1));%>
        <%BufferedImage degree=ImageIO.read(new File(deg1));%>
<%String available=com.Package1.UpdataStudentInfo.useValues(citizen, degree);%>
```

Here "add1" and "deg1" are the path of images.

In java page, I have written following code so that I could update those Image to database (Here, I had no image saved in db column previously, so I wanted to update those columns with no images). I have kept name of variables same in argument; i.e. BufferedImage citizen of jsp is BufferedImage citizen in java and BufferedImage degree of jsp is BufferedImage degree in java as well. So there is no problem in variable name.

```
 try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();   
      try{

              ByteArrayOutputStream os1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(citizen, "PNG", os1);
    ByteArrayInputStream citizen_is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os1.toByteArray());

    ByteArrayOutputStream os2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(degree, "PNG", os2);
    ByteArrayInputStream degree_is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os2.toByteArray());

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crm","root","");
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE student SET citizenship=?, degree=? WHERE sn=? ");
                stmt.setBlob(1, (Blob) citizen_is);
                     stmt.setBlob(2, (Blob) degree_is);
                     stmt.setInt(3, p);



int x=stmt.executeUpdate();

                 con.close();
}
```

I have catch statement as well to handle exception. But there is no any exception, no any runtime error and compile time error. But the image is not getting stored in the database.

Please, help me to store these two image in mysql database.

Comment: Should `int x=stmt.executeUpdate();` not be `stmt.executeUpdate();`

Comment: I have tried this as well, But this is ok... this is not the problem !!!

Comment: Does it record exists in DB?

Comment: I didn't get you Satya. But, everything is ok in DB. BLOB type is set for pictures.

Comment: How do you initialize the variable 'p'? Are you sure it's not empty and there's a record existing that matches 'select from student where sn={whatever is in p}' ?

Comment: Yes Selaron, its almost ok. It works with same code when I remove code to save image. I am able to set other columns of database with the same code. But when I try to insert image, nothing works. But there is no any error !!!

Comment: I very much doubt that `(Blob) citizen_is` does not throw an exception.  ByteArrayInputStream does not implement the Blob interface.  Try `stmt.setBytes(1, os1.toByteArray())` instead.

Comment: This didnot work as well VGR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String updateSQL = "UPDATE student SET citizenship=?, degree=? WHERE sn=? ";
File os1 = new File(filenameImageCitizenShip); //load image as file
File os2 = new File(filenameImageDegree); //load image as file
FileInputStream inputOs1 = new FileInputStream(os1);
FileInputStream inputOs2 = new FIleInputStream(os2);
try{
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crm","root","");
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(1,os1);
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(2,os2); 
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(3,p);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
  }catch(Exception e){
 }
```

Comment: caught an exceptioncom.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'citizenship' at row 1

How can i eliminate this error Vankuisher?

Comment: How is the table defined? It looks like the data is too long for the destination column. Are you able to extract a schema of your database?

Comment: Yes, I got your point and I am now able to solve that problem. Now next problem is giving me trouble. 

"caught an exceptionjava.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 11"

What is this exactly Vankuisher?

Comment: I cant stop  thanking you sir/madam, whoever you are. It worked.
Thank you so much... :) :) :) :)